# Undefined index : PATH_INFO

Tags: php

Gostaria de recuperar a URL usando `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` e tive uma bela surpresa :

> Undefined index : PATH_INFO

Pelo contrario, usando o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Qual deveria ser a origem desse erro ?
De que se trata precisamente ?

**Nota** :

- Estou num localhost :  127.0.0.1/Tuto/Site/application/index.php;
- Chamei a variavel `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` no ficheiro index.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nesse caso não tem informação pra gerar o `PATH_INFO` do [***$_SERVER***](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php), porque, ele resgata as informações adicionais em um [***URL***](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) a partir de um `script` [php](/questions/tagged/php), desconsiderando em questão as [***`Query String`***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) (informação encontrada nesse `array` [***$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']***](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php)).

<sub>O [***$_SERVER***](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php) [segundo site php.com](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php) é um `array` contendo informação como *cabeçalhos*, *paths*, e *localizações do script*.</sub>

Para resgatar esse `PATH_INFO` deve ter esse tipo de estrutura (*layout*) de [***URL***](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL):

```
http://localhost/script.php/some/all/run?g=10
```

*comando:*

```
echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
```

saída:

```
/some/all/run
```

<sup>***Observação:*** se por acaso a [***`Query String`***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) vier antes também não funciona tem que seguir essa estrutura para que a variável de ambiente seja carregada.</sup>

<sup>***Exemplo:*** `http://localhost/script.php?g=10/some/all/run`, isso não funciona para o carregamento `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.</sup>

---

Talvez não seja isso que precisa, e causa confusão com `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` que traz mais informação sobre a [***URL***](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) executada.

Como o comando `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` a saída é:

```
/script.php/some/all/run?g=10
```

trazendo informações completa da [***URL***](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) de execução de um determinado `script` [php](/questions/tagged/php).

---

***Referencias:***

- [$_SERVER](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php)
- [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)
- [URL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)
- [Get URL query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string)

Comment: Valeu ... Feliz ano novo @Virgilio!

Comment: @AndréPKA igualmente, um grande anos a todos...

Answer (score 7):

Se quiser o equivalente do `PATH_INFO` para pegar o caminho só do *path*, a solução é:

```
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
```

O `PATH_INFO`só traz o *path*, sem *query string* e outras informações, então o `PHP_SELF` é o substituto mais próximo.

### Entendendo o motivo

O `PATH_INFO` não é uma variável do PHP, é uma variável do Apache que é repassada para o PHP (mais exatamente, é uma especificação de CGI, mas o Apache repassa mesmo quando o PHP é instalado como módulo). Assim, nem é portátil, e depende de algumas condições mesmo no Apache.

Basicamente é usado quando você tem um caminho que vai além do arquivo sendo acessado, seja ele um `/meu.php/caminho`, ou um `/caminho/completo` que esteja sendo fornecido por um arquivo PHP indicado num `.htaccess`, rota ou mesmo como documento raiz do servidor (no lugar de pasta raiz).

Já o `PHP_SELF` é um indicativo do próprio script sendo executado, então no seu caso ele vai refletir o caminho que disparou o próprio PHP em uso. Importante entender a diferença para poder optar por qual usar em situações que os resultados dos dois valores são diferentes.

Mais detalhes aqui:

> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4

Comment: Feliz ano novo ... Valeu !

Comment: Igualmente, boas festas e felicidades para vc e todos os leitores.

Comment: Respondeu o que eu ia dizer eu citar *"Assim, nem é portátil, e depende de algumas condições mesmo no Apache"*, existem maneiras bem melhores do que o PATH_INFO, digo por experiencia propria +1